# OnPropertyChanged event after loading properties during runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, runtime, inotifypropertychanged

I can't imagine this is an uncommon problem, but been working at it for few days and just can't find answer. My program creates objects/properties on startup. I have a bound datagrid with datagridcheckboxcolumn that allows user to further change the object properties. The problem is the propertychanged event is hitting during the initial data load while I only want the change event to occur afterward when user uses checkboxes. Any help/direction would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    public class AvailableFolder
{
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
    private bool folderIncluded { get; set; }

    public bool FolderIncluded
    {
        get { return folderIncluded; }
        set
        {
            folderIncluded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string properName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(properName));
        }
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("property changed");

    }
}
```

At startup, it loops through and updates object properties:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < allFoldersList.Count; i++)
                {
                    string xFolderName = allFoldersList[i].FolderName;
                    string xFolderPath = allFoldersList[i].FolderPath;
                    bool xFolderIncluded = allFoldersList[i].FolderIncluded;

                    if (xFolderIncluded == false)
                    {
                        for (int r = 0; r < MainWindow.openedProject.ReleaseFolders.Count; r++)
                        {
                            string releaseFolder = MainWindow.openedProject.ReleaseFolders[r].FullReleaseFolderName;
                            if (xFolderName == releaseFolder)
                            {
                                allFoldersList[i].FolderIncluded = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                AllFoldersDataGrid.ItemsSource = allFoldersList;
```

And my datagrid xaml:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="AllFoldersDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Included" Binding="{Binding FolderIncluded, 
                Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Folder" Binding="{Binding FolderName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                <Style.Triggers >
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FolderIncluded}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You can't set some kind of "loading" flag and don't raise the event while the flag is true?

Comment: You can also make a method in AvailableFolder called "SetFolderIncludedWithoutRaisingPropertyChanged"

Comment: This worked perfectly. Still learning and this never occurred to me. Thanks SO much!!!